# Открыть предыдущую активную вкладку в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

Уважаемые знатоки vscode. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какое сочетание клавиш для открытия предыдущей открытой вкладки в данном редакторе?

Не сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, которое открывает последнюю закрытую вкладку, а именно сочетание для открытия вкладки которая была в фокусе перед текущей.

Answer (score 2):

Решение данного вопроса довольно простое и на поверхности. Сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Однако есть и ещё две комбинации делающие аналогичные действия: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd> причём каждое повторное нажатие последних клавиш в комбинациях будут опускать вас ниже в стеке просмотра вкладок. Я же для себя оставил первый вариант: правый <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Думаю левши поймут почему.

Comment: Вроде Ctrl+Tab и Ctrl+Shift+Tab переключают вкладки по порядку, а не в порядке использования?

Comment: Хм.. Проверил - действительно, переключение в порядке использования. Кстати, для своего варианта я нашёл аналоги с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1):

На мышке нажать кнопку <kbd>back</kbd>. Если были перемщения в текущей вкладке, то придётся нажать несколько раз. Если в текущее место попал через <kbd>back</kbd>, то нажать наоборот <kbd>forward</kbd>.

Очень удобная навигация - постоянно пользуюсь.

Впрочем, у этих кнопок есть замена на клавиатуре: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Влево</kbd> и <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Вправо</kbd>.

[image: фото]

Comment: на мышке нажать back? кастомная мыша?

Comment: @KoVadim, любая с 5+ кнопками. Можно от 200-300 рублей купить. Немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: ага, особенно на тачпаде. И где же за 200-300 рублей можно купить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Хороший ответ, но не в тему

Comment: @KoVadim, ну владельцам тачпадов не повезло)) Купить - да где угодно - вот подборка на яндекс-маркете с фильтром на 5 кнопок и сортировкой по возрастанию цены: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Wbe.png.

Comment: @ПавелБулин, не понял, почему не в тему.

Comment: нет никакого яндекс маркета:)

Comment: @KoVadim, я с тех пор, как мышь с этими кнопками попробовал, на обычную возвращаться не хочу)) Только надо чтобы кнопки были нормально расположены и случайно не нажимались.

Comment: я рад за Вас, но проблема в другом.

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что: первое я сейчас например не могу себе позволить данную покупку

Comment: @второе даже если бы и мог позволить то пользоваться всем функционалом данной мыши не смог бы так как левша. Поэтому вопрос и был задан исходя из контекста доступных мне ресурсов.  Да и в конце концов здесь вроде бы форум программистов, а не витрина товаров.

Comment: @ПавелБулин, во-первых, ответы не только для того, кто спрашивает, но и для тех, кто придёт из поиска - им может пригодиться. Что касается левой руки, то такие мыши для левой руки есть. Причём, в нескольких вариантах: полноценная для левой руки (https://i.stack.imgur.com/urh8i.png), симметричная с 7 кнопками (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtPv.png) и симметричная с кнопками справа (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0r5F.png). Впрочем, минимальный ценник явно выше. Что касается сравнения с витриной товаров - я ж не предлагаю какой-то конкретный товар, я говорю про фичу, которая может оказаться полезной.

Comment: @KoVadim, проблема в тачпаде? Я нашёл замену с клавиатуры.

Comment: мне это не нужно, я пользуюсь более продвинутыми редакторами обычно.